# Maven build failure for Spring boot with Alexa skill kit

Tags: java, spring-boot, alexa-skills-kit

I tried to build the spring boot project for AWS lambda and deploy it. I try to use the following command:

```
 mvn assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies package
```

to create a .JAR file.

My output:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ requestTestDemoFromAWSLambda ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.668 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-23T17:06:21+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 89M/538M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project requestTestDemoFromAWSLambda: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to rename 'D:\alexaWork\requestTestDemoFromAWSLambda\target\requestTestDemoFromAWSLambda-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' to 'D:\alexaWork\requestTestDemoFromAWSLambda\target\requestTestDemoFromAWSLambda-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

As you see is not working